# This site can't be reached if more then 10 users login in the system

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, mod-security

I am working on a small project where the users can log in using their own login details.
Each user has with different username and password. I have a webpage which is on CodeIgniter. I am using below code for user login.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
  {
   $this->checkLogin();
  }

public function checkLogin(){
  if(!$this->session->userdata('login_session'))
    {
     $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('crmid', 'CRM id', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {
        $this->load->view('login');
       }
      else
        {
        $crmid = strtoupper($this->input->post('crmid'));
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $result=$this->Access_model->check_password($crmid,$password);//varifying password

        if ($result) {
        //creating session
        $login_emp_session = array('id' => $result->id,'crmid'  =>$result->crm_id,'firstname' => $result->firstname,'lastname' => $result->lastname,'access_role' => $result->access_role,'password_change_status' => $result->password_change_status);
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_session',$login_emp_session);//set the session   

             if ($result->password_change_status == 0) {
                 redirect("Access_control/changepassword");//calling change password
                }
            else{
              redirect("Dashboard_control/dashboard");//calling dashboard
                }
       }
  else{
      $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid_password', 'Invalid username and password');
      $this->load->view('login');
     }

 }
     }
     else
        {
        if ($this->session->userdata['login_session']['password_change_status'] == 0) {
             $this->session->sess_destroy();
             $this->load->view('login');

            }
         else{
          redirect("Dashboard_control/dashboard");//calling employee register
        }
        }

        }
```

If the single user or 2-3 user login in the system then everything is working perfectly but the users are logged in more than 10 systems with the public IP (which is shared IP )and after 10-25 min I am getting the message `This site can't be reached`.

So I contact the Hostgator team, They said there is no issue with your IP address please check your code again. There is some issue with ModSecurity and we can't enable it.

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 409 (phase 1)
```

Is my login in code is correct?
would you help me out on this issue?

This is the logs which I got from hostgator.

```
[Tue Apr 09 17:12:51.564509 2019] [:error] [pid 947073:tid 140357593020160] [client *.*.*.*:0] [client *.*.*.*] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/OWASP3/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf"] [line "37"] [id "980130"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 10 - SQLI=0,XSS=0,RFI=0,LFI=10,RCE=0,PHPI=0,HTTP=0,SESS=0): Path Traversal Attack (/../)"] [tag "event-correlation"] [hostname "abc.mydomain.com"] [uri "/errors/404_Forbidden_php.php"] [unique_id "XKzSkDANRUc4aj6DxXxtsQAAAmk"], referer: http://abc.mydomain.com/Access_control/index
```

Comment: can anyone help me out with this issue? or any idea?

Comment: It sounds like Hostgator have rate limiting set up on ModSecurity. They need to give you more details on the ModSecurity error and how to resolve it.

Comment: @BarryPollard, They are telling me to change the code. I don't understand what is the issue with my code.

Comment: They are wrong. Or at least I can’t see why they would be right until they give more information.

Comment: @BarryPollard, I updated logs in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the wrong logs. ModSecurity detects any errors (which increased the inbound)anomaly_score), and then makes a decision based on the total score. You have shown the log files of the final decision, but not the preceding log files showing what trigger that decision. Either way your hosting provider needs to help you fix this.

Comment: @BarryPollard, Thanks for the information. I am contacting again Hostgator team.